# Display data on console and also save data to text file.

Tags: java, io

So here is my code, it seems to work, but it just prints out the info on file rather than doing both (displaying data on console and saving the information to a text file). Help appreciated.

```
   // imports
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintStream;

   public class DTM {

       // The main method for our Digital Terrain Models
       /** @param args
        * @throws IOException
        */
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


           //Prints the console output on a text file (Output.txt)
           PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
           System.setOut(out);

           //Declare some variables
           int aRows = 401;
           int bCols = 401;
           String DMTfile = "sk28.asc";
           //Declare some tables
           double data[][] = new double[aRows][bCols];

           BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DMTfile));
           //Write data into array
           for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++) {
               String rowArray[] = file.readLine().split(" ");
               for (int j = 0; j < bCols; j++) {
                   data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(rowArray[j]);
               }
           }

           //Closing the file
           file.close();

           //print out the array
           for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < bCols; j++) {
                   System.out.println(data[i][j]);
               }
           }

           // this hold's the smallest number
           double high = Double.MIN_VALUE;
           // this hold's the biggest number
           double low = Double.MAX_VALUE;

           //initiate a "For" loop to act as a counter through an array
           for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++)

               //determine the highest value
               if (data[i][j] > high) {
                   high = data[i][j];
               }
               //determine the lowest value
               else if (data[i][j] < low) {
                   low = data[i][j];

               }
           }

           // Code here to find the highest number
           System.out.println("Peak in this area = " + high);
           // Code here to find the lowest number
           System.out.println("Dip in this area = " + low);

       }
   }
```

Comment: Why not just call your own function ... that does two writes ... instead of redirecting System.out???

Comment: Only if I knew how to do that, thanks for your advice thou.

Comment: See ailnlv's "multiPrint()" below.  I would: 1) remove your System.setOut(out), 2) make "PrintStream "out" a private class member variable, 3) call the method "println()", 3) call `System.out.println(s);` and `out.println(s);` inside your new, DTM-specific "println()" method.
    out.write(s);

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Apache Commons TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html).

Untested, but should do the tric:

```
outStream = System.out;   
// only the file output stream  
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output.txt", true);   
// create a TeeOutputStream that duplicates data to outStream and os  
os = new TeeOutputStream(outStream, os); 
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(os);       
System.setOut(printStream);
```

Comment: I would just write my desired results to the TeeOutputStream - setting System.out globally is quite a drastic step. If you really want that behavior (copying all of stdout to a file), better to do that from a shell script than programmatically.

Comment: It depends...but the PO did already overwrite the stdout, so i reused that.

Answer (score 1):

You're merely redirecting standard output to a file instead of the console. As far as I know there is no way to automagically clone an output onto two streams, but it's pretty easy to do it by hand:

```
public static void multiPrint(String s, FileOutputStream out){
    System.out.print(s);
    out.write(s);
}
```

Whenever you want to print you just have to call this function:

```
FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
multiPrint("hello world\n", out);
```